# Rewrite Rule htaccess signature from png to php with get parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, png, signature

I want to redirect
`signature.png?uid=1234`
to
`signature.php?uid=1234`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^signature.png\?uid=[0-9]+ signature.php?uid=$1 [L]
```

does not work. where is my fault?

Answer (score 1):

Query string parameters are automatically passed

```
Redirect permanent /signature.png http://www.example.com/signature.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't match against the query string (everything after the `?`) in a rewrite rule. In fact, since the query string isn't being changed at all, you don't need to match for it at all because it automatically gets appended to the end of the rewrite. You just need to match the URI:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^signature.png$ signature.php [L]
```